# How to make procedure iterate on every item in a list in Scheme?

Tags: graph, scheme, racket

I am writing a function in Scheme with Advanced Student settings. The function traverses through graph G and looks if there is a path between vertex X and Y. It "kinda" works, but not in all cases. I know where the problem lies, but I am not sure how to fix it. First I look if the vertex X I am looking on has been visited, if not I continue and mark it as visited. Then there is function find-adju. That function returns list of all of neighbours for given vertex. For example if I had a graph like this:

```
(define-struct graph (vertices edges))
(define-struct vertice (name visited))
(define-struct edge (start-vertice end-vertice length))

(define vertices-list
  (list (make-vertice 0 0)
        (make-vertice 1 0)
        (make-vertice 2 0)
        (make-vertice 3 0)
        (make-vertice 4 0)
        )
  )

(define edges-list
  (list (make-edge 0 1 0)
        (make-edge 0 2 0)
        (make-edge 1 3 0)
        (make-edge 2 0 0)
        (make-edge 2 4 0)
        (make-edge 4 2 0)
        )
)
(define G (make-graf vertices-list edge-list))
(traverse-graph? 0 4 G)
```

Then for given vertex 0 it would return list(1 2). Next I look at the list and ask, if my desired vertex Y is in it. If not, look again recursively at the first item in the list. But in doing so I lose information about all the other neighbours. In the same case, it would look at vertex 1, find all of his neighbours and then the procedure would quit, because it did not find a way. But the vertex 2 then remains unvisited. How can I make the procesure look at every item in the lsit and not just the first one?

```
(define (traverse-graph X Y G)
  (cond
    [(not(eq? (vertex-visited (find-vertex X (graph-vertices G))) VISITED))
     (begin
       (set-vertex-visited! (find-vertex X (graph-vertices G)) VISITED)
       (cond
         [(member Y (find-adju X (graph-edges G))) #t]
         [(not (empty? (find-adju X (graph-edges G)))) (traverse-graph (car (find-adju X (graph-edges G))) Y G) ]
         [else #f]
         )
       )
     ]
    [else #f]
    )
  )
```

I thought of maybe returning the whole list with cdr instead of car to the traverse-function, but I don't know how to implement that. And how would I deal with the first step where X is a number and not a list.

EDIT:

I tried adding for-each which seems to be working ok, but the result is not giving me anything. No true or false. If I debug it step by step, I see that it is probably traversing correctly but when it reaches the [(member condition, it stops without returning anything, even when the condition is true.

```
(define (traverse-graph X Y G)
  (cond
    [(not(eq? (vertex-visited (find-vertex X (graph-vertices G))) VISITED))
     (begin
       (set-vertex-visited! (find-vertex X (graph-vertices G)) VISITED)
       (cond
         [(member Y (find-adju X (graph-edges G))) #t]
         [(not (empty? (find-adju X (graph-edges G)))) 
            (for-each (lambda (h)
                  (traverse-graph h Y G)
                  ) (find-adju X (graph-edges G))
                    )
          ]
         [else #f]
         )
       )
     ]
    [else #f]
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right path with [`for-each`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html?q=for-each#%28def._htdp-advanced._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._for-each%29%29), but that function is an imperative construct. For each edge in your list it says "do this, do that", but does not keep any value. You would have more luck with [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html?q=for-each#%28def._htdp-advanced._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._map%29%29), which iterates over the list, and aggregates the results in a list.

With [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html?q=for-each#%28def._htdp-advanced._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._map%29%29), the result of your traverse-graph will be a tree with the shape of a depth-first-search traversal:

```lisp
'(result0 (result1 (result3))
          (result2 (result4)))
```

---

You could use `(apply append (map (lambda …) (find-adju …))` to append the list of lists at each step, and prepend with [`cons`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html?q=for-each#%28def._htdp-advanced._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._cons%29%29) the result for the current node. Don't forget to return a list containing a single element for the leaf nodes of your traversale, i.e use `'(#t)` and `'(#f)`. This has however a big drawback the time complexity is `O(N²)` in the worst case. Imagine a graph where each node has two children: a leaf as its right child, and the rest of the graph as its left child:

```lisp
(→ 0 2)    (→ 0 1)
(→ 2 4)    (→ 2 3)
(→ 4 6)    (→ 4 5)
(→ 6 8)    (→ 6 7)
(→ 8 10)   (→ 8 9)
…
(→ 96 98)  (→ 96 97)
(→ 98 100) (→ 98 99)
```

With that graph, your traversal will start drilling down the left edges until it reaches the leftmost node (`100`),

- then return from that to node `98`, go down to `99`, and back up to `98`, where it will append `'(result100)` to `'(result99)` and prepend `result98`,
- then it will move back up to `96`, examine `97`, move back to `96`, and append `'(result98 result100 result99)` to `'(result97) and prepend`result96`,
- …
- then it will move back up to `0`, examine `1`, move back to `0`, and append `'(… many results here …)` to `'(result1)`, and prepend `result0`.

Since `append` has to copy all the elements from the prefix, appending a list of length `n` to a list of length `m` will cost `n` operations (the second list is simply pointed to, and doesn't need to be copied, as the tail it forms is identical to the original whole second list), i.e it costs `O(n)` operations. The sequence of calls to [`append`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html?q=for-each#%28def._htdp-advanced._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._append%29%29) will be:

```lisp
append 1 element to 1 element
append 3 elements to 1 element
append 5 elements to 1 element
append 7 elements to 1 element
append 9 elements to 1 element
…
append 99 elements to 1 element
```

So the total cost is 1+3+5+…+N, where N is the total number of nodes, which is roughly equivalent to N² times constant factor, hence the `O(n²)`, which means that for a large number of nodes, it will be very slow. More about this [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

---

To avoid the `O(N²)` cost, you can use an accumulator: each step will prepend a single item to the accumulator, and pass it around. This means that when handling a node, you have to give the current accumulator to its first neighbour, get back the modified accumulator for that whole sub-tree, pass that to the second neighbour, get back a new modified accumulator, pass that to the third neighbour, etc.

For that, you could write your own recursive function over the list, taking the latest accumulator and the list as an argument, and making a recursive call with the modified accumulator (obtained by processing the whole sub-tree), and the tail of the list.

You could also use the [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html?q=for-each#%28def._htdp-advanced._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) function which abstracts over this pattern. The node-processing function will then follow this structure:

```lisp
(define (process node accumulator)
  (foldl ; the function applied to each neighbour of the list,
         ; it is passed the neighbour and the accumulator returned
         ; by the previous iteration
         (lambda (neighbour latest-accumulator)
           (if (visited? neighbour)
               (process neighbour latest-accumulator)
               latest-accumulator)) ; return unchanged
         ; initial accumulator for the first iteration,
         ; we already prepend the result for the current node,
         ; but that could be done afterwards, by prepending
         ; to the final result of `foldl`.
         (cons (compute-result-for node) accumulator)
         ; the list of neighbours:
         (neighbours-of node)))
```

Since this does never append lists, instead just prepending a single result at each step, it has a complexity of `O(N)` (without counting the cost of the `neighbours-of` function, see the note on hash tables and sets below). The flow of data is a bit convoluted though, sadly there's no better option with immutable data structures.

---

In your specific case, since you return a boolean, you could also simply use [`ormap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html#%28def._htdp-advanced._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._ormap%29%29), which will iterate over the list and return `#t` if the `lambda` returned `#t` for any element.

Does this have the O(N²) complexity like [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html?q=for-each#%28def._htdp-advanced._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._map%29%29)? Think about why it does not.

---

As a side note, you should use `#f` and `#t` instead of `0` and `VISITED`, or `#f` and `'visited` (the quoted `'` symbol `visited`, which is considered true in an `if` statement, like all values other than `#f`).

For better performance, use hash tables and sets to store the edges, as looking for the edges in a list will cost a lot if there are many edges.

Finally, I would suggest putting the closing parenthesis of a block of code at the end of the last line, instead of having them alone on their line. This is the common practice in Scheme, Racket and most other Lisp variants, and makes the code more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

"but when it reaches the [(member condition, it stops without returning anything, even when the condition is true."

Check first if the list produced by

```
 (find-adju X (graph-edges G)))
```

is empty. Then check if the list is non-empty and if Y is in that list. Then have an else case, where the list is non-empty but Y is not in the list of immediate neighbors.

Comment: I got kind of lost. Could you show me an exact piece of code?